# Why does my outdoor cat always waiting for me and only me to pet it?

Tags: cats

I live in a small house with 5 people inside. Years ago my cat had escaped the house and came back 1 week later. My mom won't let him inside and I feel bad for him. He usually waits for me outside of the door staring at me then when I go outside and pet him he starts purring. However, he only waits for me when my mom pets him too. He's been outside for over 7 years and he so far has no ticks but I can't tell if he has worms or other stuff.

How come my cat only waits for me to pet him?
And how do I convince my mom to let him inside?

Comment: What is her fear of the cat? Is the cat neutered? I'm guessing it hasn't had it's shots in quite some time?

Comment: The cat has been neutered. I think she just doesn't want to take him in because yes he hasn't got shots in years and also my cousins are allergic she babysits them daily. But I could just volunteer to vacuum the floors and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know why your mom doesn’t want him back in?

We got our kitten from the pound and he had fleas, was sick, and needed neutered. It was super overwhelming but actually all rather easy to take care of. There are affordable options to take care of cats without going to the vet. You can buy tick, flea, ear mite stuff at local grocery stores and pet stores. So, if your mom has issues about the cat being dirty maybe you could assure her you can affordably take care of it! Also maybe suggest if you can keep the cat in your room or the litter box in your bathroom, etc. She may just not want to take care of the cat.

As far as the cat waiting for you, he likes you! I’ve looked some things up in the past and they said cats will usually hang around those they trust and like the most. The cat may just be the most familiar with you (your smell, etc.) verses the others. You’ve treated him well and I think he knows that!

Answer (score 1):

Cats generally pick one human as their favorite, and others are mostly just tolerated (or not). The fact that he's "your cat" actually means that he has decided you're *his human*.

You'll have to edit the question to explain *why* your mother won't let him inside for us to be able to address that part. Or you can split that off to a separate question.